# Visual Studio: linking diagrams with the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, uml, alm

I work with VS2010, but can switch to any other version if it would help.

I need to find a tool in Visual Studio that would allow me to link a logical diagram of the steps of the program with the code behind each step.

So, I need the following:

1) a tool to draw a diagram of the steps;

2) when i click on an element of the diagram, Visual Studio opens a piece of C# code that I initially associated with this step.

I see that there are plenty of tools in the Application Lifecycle Management in VS2010. But I'm a bit confused which particular tool would do what I've described.

In the picture below I presented an example diagram consisting of three steps:

1) Check the existence of files

2) Unzip the files

3) Copy the files into the destination folder

My requirement is the following:

I click on "Check the existence of files" and Visual Studio goes to the piece of code that is assigned to this step and I can edit this piece of code.

In other words, the elements of the diagram are a kind of bookmarks for the pieces of code.

Any help is very much appreciated. Any suggestions how to achieve the same result but with different tools are also very welcome!

Thanks a lot for all the comments!

[image: example diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to this I am aware of is [windows workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734702%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  IME, WF tends to be useful because it allows non-programmers to build applications as a series of steps rather than as code.  In other words, WF isn't something I recommend solely for it's "UML" or code diagramming features.  It certainly has a powerful state machine / flowchart like code designer.

Here's a state machine flowchart from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735945%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed! By the way, do you have any idea why in VS2010 it requires SharePoint? What kind of features of SharePoint does it use?

Comment: @user2925546 - Glad the info is useful!  Goodness...I don't remember that being a requirement back when I did WF?  Sorry I haven't the faintest.